# Cannot connect to open port in remote server

Tags: networking, tcp, remote-access, elasticsearch

On my remote server, I installed `ElasticSearch`, which can be accessed at `http://localhost:9200/`:

[image]

I defined an inbound security rule, `Port9200`, in the firewall for my remote server:

[image]

[image]

As you can see, Port 9200 is publicly accessible to everybody.

When I tried to access the remote `ElasticSearch` server from the browser in my local computer, I saw the following time-out message:

[image]

**My router firewall does not have any rules blocking outbound traffic to any TCP port.**

Any suggestions on how to make my remote ElasticSearch server accessible from my local machine?

Answer (score 2):

Check on which IP address your ElasticSearch installation is listening on. If it is only listening on `localhost` you won't reach it from another machine even if the firewall rules are in place.
You can check it with `netstat -ano|find "9200"` on a `cmd`.